# Clear CMake's internal cache

Tags: caching, opencv, cmake

I am sure there is a simple command for this.

I had installed opencv 2.4.3 manually in /usr/local.

Then I removed it and installed OpenCV 2.4.5 from the arch community(I am using Arch linux) which gets installed in /usr

Now when I try to use OpenCV in a cmake project, cmake returns the old paths from /usr/local.

I did some digging around and found that if remove "CACHE" from the line:
get_filename_component(OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH ="${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATCH CACHE)
in /usr/share/opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake I get the correct path.

This points to my question. How do I clear the cmake cache?I am talking about cmake's internal cache not the application's cache which can be deleted by removing CMakeCache.txt.  Is there  a command? Or where is the cmake cache directory/file located? I am sure there's a simple answer for this.
I know how to set/unset a CACHE variable, but don't know how to clear the complete cache.

Comment: You can delete CMakeCache.txt file from your build directory.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I am not talking about the cache for the application. I am talking about CMake's internal cache. OpenCVConfig.cmake is used every time cmake is run for the application to find OpenCV libraries.

Comment: The only cache CMake maintains is the one stored in CMakeCache.txt in your build directory.  There is no system-wide cache.

Comment: Are you sure? I have cleared the app's cache by deleting CMakeCache.txt,in fact,I cleared the build directory.If you read my question, cmake's behaviour changes when I modify the file OpenCVConfig.cmake(which has NOTHING to do with my application) by removing the text "CACHE". I also read in cmake's docs that get_filename_component() is called everytime cmake is invoked. Even when the application's cache is cleared, cmake reported wrong paths for OpenCV's libraries(/usr/local/lib/lib_opencv* instead of /usr/lib/lib_opencv*) so cmake must be storing the old values somewhere? –

Comment: It's possible that whatever you're using to find openCV is looking at /usr/local before /usr.  Have you tried remove/renaming/whatever opencv under /usr/local?

Comment: The problem was with pkg-config settings. I hadn't removed the old .pc file and adjusted the PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

Comment: @RichardMacwan Please consider adding your solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer. It helps others clearly see the solution at a glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with pkg-config settings. I hadn't removed the old .pc file and adjusted the PKG_CONFIG_PATH. pkg-config was using the opencv.pc file present in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig rather than the one present in /usr/lib/pkgconfig. There isn't any cache that cmake uses internally, i think.

Comment: There is some internal cache that keeps a few settings even if the cache file is deleted, but deleting the cache file while CMake is not open solves possible problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling the dependency library solved my problem.

I have a project that depends on Opencv. When I still using Xcode 7.2beta, the path of SDK of MacOSX is "/Applications/**xcode7.2beta.app**/Content/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/**MacOSX10.11.sdk**". So, the cmake generated and compiled opencv libraries with MacOSX10.11.sdk under "/Applications/xcode7.2beta.app/".

A few days ago, I upgraded my xcode to 8.0, the new path of xcode and its SDK is "/Applications/**xcode.app**/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/**MacOSX10.12.sdk**". But anyway, when cmake generates my project, the reference to opencv always points to the old xcode.

Later I realized that opencv was generated using the old Xcode, so I re-compiled the opencv with the new Xcode, and my project was compiled correctly.